# full text search in databases

Tags: search, elasticsearch, solr, full-text-search

I have two fairly general question about full text search in a database. I was looking into elastic search and solr and it seems to me that one needs to produce separate documents made up of table entries, which then get searched. So the result of such a search is not actually a database entry? Or did I misunderstand something?

I also looked into whoosh search, which does index table columns and the result of whoosh are actual table rows. 
When using solr or elastic search, should I put the row id into the document which gets searched and after I have my result use that id to retrieve the relevant rows from the table? Or is there a better solution?

Another question I have is if I have a id like abc/123.64664, which is stored as a string, is there any advantage in searching such a column with a FTS? It seems to me there is not much to be gained by indexing? Or am I wrong?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

Elasticsearch can store the indexed document, and you can retrieve it as a part of query result. Usually ppl still store the original data in an usual DB, it gives you more reliability and flexibility on reindexing. Mind that ES indexes non-relational data. You can have you data stored in relational manner and compose denormalized documents for indexing.

As for "abc/123.64664" you can index it as tokenized string or you can tune the index for prefix search etc. It's up to you

Answer (score 0):

**(TL;DR)** Don't think about what your data is structured in your RDBS. Think about what you are **searching**.

---

Content storage for good full text search is quite different from relational database standard storage. So, your data going into Search Engine can end up looking quite differently from the way you stored it.

This is all driven by your expected **search results**. You may increase granularity of the data or - opposite - denormalize it so the parent/related record content shows up in the records you actually want returned as part of search. Text processing (copyField, tokenization, pre-processing, etc) is also where a lot of content modifications happen to make a record findable.

Sometimes, relational databases support full-text search. PostgreSQL is getting better and better at that. But most of the time, relational databases just do not provide enough flexibility to support good relevancy-driven search.

Finally, if the original schema is quite complex, it may make sense to only use search engine to get the right - relevant - IDs out and then merge them in the client code with the details from the original database records.